# Error when execuuting Before Insert Trigger

Tags: oracle, insert, mod-plsql

I have an Oracle, apex application with a MasterDetail Form.
I need to do a BeforeInsert Trigger for the details part of the form. 
I need to populate the fields for the BEFOREINSERT_CHARGES with the data from another table (AHAR_PARTSLABOR)
This is what I have so far yet it keeps giving me a message error:

> ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger BEFOREINSERT_CHARGES
BEFORE INSERT
On AHAR_REPAIRORDER_CHARGES

--DECLARAR VARIABLES
     --T_CHARGES_TYPE IN CHAR(11);
     --T_CHARGES_PRICE IN NUMBER;
     --T_CHARGES_DISCOUNT IN NUMBER; 

    --VALIDAR QUE EL CHAR_CODE INGRESADO POR EL USUARIO EXISTA

BEGIN

--SELECT PARA PASAR LOS VALORES DE PARTSLABOR A CHARGES 

    SELECT (PARTLABOR_TYPE, PARTLABOR_PRICE, PARTLABOR_DISCOUNT)
    INTO (:NEW.CHARGES_TYPE, :NEW.CHARGES_PRICE, :NEW.HARGES_DISCOUNT)

    FROM AHAR_PARTSLABOR
    WHERE :NEW.CHARGE_CODE = PARTLABOR_ID;

END;
```

Comment: :NEW and :OLD are meta for the table.  You can't select into them - they exist only as far as the current transaction is alive, and only for the table that the before insert references. AHAR_REPAIRORDER_CHARGES.  You need to do your select prior to the insert to begin with.  At that point, the trigger is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to change the `:new` values you have to use a "for each row" trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger BEFOREINSERT_CHARGES
BEFORE INSERT
On AHAR_REPAIRORDER_CHARGES FOR EACH ROW
```